# How to move radio button text below radio button

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

[image: I want user to choose one them]

I have tried RadioGroup buttons.  It's working but the text is next to the radio button. I want the text to be below the button .
Is there a way to do that or another way  to make the same task.

Here is the RadioGroup:

```
      <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/fisrt_imgtoselect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_new_order_specifications"
            android:button="@drawable/img_moder_classic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/second_imgtoselect"
            android:button="@drawable/img_classic"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_new_order_specifications"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/third_imgtoselect"
            android:button="@drawable/img_classic"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_new_order_specifications"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem with more details ? And can you show me the code where you set Text under your Radio buttons?

Comment: I want to do something like the photo the user can choose only on choice of these

Answer (score 0):

Use `DrawableTop` to put the drawable up and text below

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radios"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/my_icon"
        android:text="first"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/my_icon"
        android:text="second"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="right"/>


</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: it works but i think radio button not for what i want ,because when i select  one of the button the whole background changes , i want to change the back ground of the image and the color of the text

Comment: Is there another way to do what i want

Comment: This is the code i used, i ask if i want to do something like the photo allows user to choose one of them ,What is the correct way should i use ,thanks for helping me

Comment: The current code with radio group allows the user to select only one. `radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener` should tell you the currently selected radio button.

Comment: it is right but when i  set selector to the one user clicked the whole back ground color of button changed included the space between the text and the image , I want to change only the text color and the frame of the image like the photo above

Comment: i use the code above and radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener  when the image is pressed  android:background="@drawable/selector_new_order_specifications" , to change the back ground of button